# Complete, Finitely Axiomatizable, Theory with 3 Countable Models

Tags: logic, model-theory

Does there exist a complete, finitely axiomatizable, first-order theory $T$ with exactly 3 countable non-isomorphic models?

A few relevant comments:

There is a classical example of a complete theory with exacly $3$ models. This theory is not finitely axiomatizable (For the trivial reason that the language is infinite).

In [this post, Javier Moreno](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69/complete-theory-with-exactly-n-countable-models) explains how to rephrase this example in a finite language. Still, the theory is not finitely axiomatizable.

Some less relevant comments:

I would like to know if finite axiomability has ever be asked in this context.

There have been research in connection with stability. Lachlan has proved that a superstable theory with finitely many countable models is $\omega$-categorical. And it is still open if this can be extended to all stable theories.

Comment: @James pointed out my misreading of the Question that these 3 countable nonisomorphic models are the only models, interpreting instead that among its countable models, there are exactly three isomorphism classes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, which make the question much more accessible to someone who hasn't thought about such things before.

Comment: Wilfred Hodges' *Model Theory* theorem 12.2.18 states that a totally categorical theory $T$ (a) is not finitely axiomatisable and (b) is **quasi-finitely axiomatisable**; where the latter property means that it is definitionally equivalent to a single sentence together with all the sentences "there are at least $n$ elements" for each $n$. And further that an $\omega$-stable and $\omega$-categorical $T$ is not finitely axiomatisable either. (So your second question--has anybody thought about these questions before?--has answer "yes". Hodges says the theorem answers a conjecture of Vaught.)

Comment: Note though that the usual Ehrenfeucht example of a 3-model theory is *un*stable.

Comment: This post might give you a lead, but I don't have David Marker's model theory book -- http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143394/are-all-complete-finitely-axiomatizable-first-order-theories-aleph-0-categori

Comment: Do you mean that there are $n\ge 3$ models, but only $3$ isomorphically distinct models, or that there are $3$ models, and they are not isomorphic?

Comment: @DanielV There are 3 models up to isomorphism. "Up to isomorphism" is usually left implicit. If you do not count "up to isomorphism" there is always a proper class of models.

Comment: Let ∆ be the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints (finitely axiomatizable), then the classic Ehrenfeucht example theory T is axiomatized by $∆∪\{c_k<c_{k+1} | k ∈ ω\}$ which has 3 countable models up to isomorphism. If you want it to be finitely axiomatized, we can simply *syntactically* change above set of countably infinite number of axioms to a *single* $\Pi_1$ sentence: $\forall k. c_k<c_{k+1}$ where $k$ ranges over another sort of natural number type. This theory's alphabet is infinite, but it by no means we cannot have a finitely axiomatized theory using this language.

Comment: @mohottnad That doesn't help at all. "$\forall k.c_k<c_{k+1}$" is **not** a first-order sentence: first-order logic doesn't let you quantify over symbol indices like that. And re: "If you want it to be finitely axiomatized," finite axiomatizability is **the whole point of** the question (see e.g. the passage "There is a classical example of a complete theory with exacly 3
3 models. This theory is not finitely axiomatizable (For the trivial reason that the language is infinite).")

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks for your critique and I agree my above sentence is not well formed. However, similarly here's some [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155201/does-every-first-order-theory-have-a-finitely-axiomatizable-conservative-exten) suggests "every recursively axiomatizable theory in first-order logic with identity that has only infinite models, has a finitely axiomatized conservative extension... simply endow the given theory with a new sort.." which seems applicable here for above theory with 3 countable models. Another way for a single sentence using $L_{w1,w}$ logic?

Comment: @mohottnad It is **not** true that if $T$ is a conservative extension (even in the "strong" sense) of $S$ then $T$ has the same number of countable models (up to isomorphism) as $S$; the "additional structure" of $T$ may introduce additional models. All we can say is that there will be the same number of *reducts to the language of $S$* of countable models of $T$, up to isomorphism, as there are countable models of $S$ up to isomorphism. But that's much weaker. As to changing to $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$, note that changing the logic **also** changes the meaning of "complete," *(cont'd)*

Comment: and by Scott's theorem a complete $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-theory has at most one countable model up to isomorphism (as long as the language is countable, anyways); actually, Scott showed that for every countable structure $\mathcal{A}$ (in a countable language), there is a **single** $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence $\varphi$ such that for all countable $\mathcal{B}$ we have $\mathcal{B}\models\varphi\iff\mathcal{B}\cong\mathcal{A}$ (google "Scott sentence"). So none of this is relevant.